# SQL Alias Works on One Server, Not Another

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

I have SQL aliases setup identically on two different client (SharePoint) servers.   On one server, everything works fine.  On the other server, I get an error from SSMS that says "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible."  I created a dummy text file and named it test.udl.  When I double click it, put in the  alias for the server name and click Test Connection, I get "Test connection succeeded".  Anybody have any idea what's going on here?